# Can't resolve './reducer ' in '/Users/apple/Desktop/my-app/src

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I used to use redux with javascript and this my first time I use redux with typescript.
Till now I'm just trying to see it in action but, I faced this error with vscode HINTs says `'interface' declarations can only be used in TypeScript files.`

also I found people use

```
module.exports = {
  someMethod: (param: string): string => {
    return param;
  },
}
```

but I don't what is it?

## here are my files

1. `src/reducer.ts`

```
interface Note {
  note: string[];
}
const intialState = { notes: [] };
type Actions = { type: "Add_note"; payload: string };

export const noteReducer = (state: Note = intialState, action: Actions) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "Add_note": {
      return { ...state, notes: [...state.notes, action.payload] };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

2. `src/store.ts`

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { noteReducer } from "./reducer ";
const store = createStore(noteReducer);
export default store;
```

3. `src/index.tsx`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./store";
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: Is it inside an .ts file?

Comment: @Jesper1 all my files are .ts files

Comment: Can you change the file to .tsx?

Comment: @All there is an extra space in your import: `import { noteReducer } from "./reducer ";` should be `import { noteReducer } from "./reducer";`

Comment: yes thank you so much, maybe I wasn't able to focus because I overworked